# making use of string pointer to print the character-integer combinations

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have C function that takes string pointer as a parameter. This functions returns as symbol which  is pointed by the pointer. I would like to generate = many symbols depending upon the requirements. Suppose, i have four doors in a house. I would like to give different names to different doors like  `d1,d2,d3....`. In this case , i would like to create a string pointer which points to both string and integer so that i can get the symbols which differ by only numerical values. This helps me to categorize the symbols seeing the string value. I would like to know how can i declare a string pointer so that i can create a symbol that i mentioned above.

[EDIT]

I will try to make it clear.

I have array of two pointers

```
const char *test[] ={"a","12345"}
```

I would like make the pointer to point a and 1 and a and 2 and .... so on. Is there any method to do it?

Comment: I don't get it. Are you looking for parsing the given string in order to extract the digits?

Comment: Do you simply want to combine each single letter from the first string with each single letter from the second string?

Comment: @thkala, yes i would like to combine first letter with other  letters so as to give the different name to a same kind of symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question is so ambiguous, here's yet another one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    const char *test[] = { "a", "12345" };

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; test[0][i] != 0; ++i)
        for (j = 0; test[1][j] != 0; ++j)
            printf("%c%c\n", test[0][i], test[1][j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
```

Answer (score 1):

A string is a pointer to characters, therefore you cannot point to integers. You can do some conversion work, but that doesn't seem suitable to your problem. What you need is a structure.

Implementing your example:

```
struct Doors {
    int num;
    char sym;
} d1, d2, d3;

d1.sym = 'd';
d1.num = 1;

d2.sym = 'd';
d2.num = 2;

d3.sym = 'd';
d3.num = 3;
```

**EDIT**:

My solution modified as an implementation of your second example:

```
struct Doors {
    int * nums;
    const char * sym;
} d;

int n = 3; // Amount of doors.
d.nums = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int)); // Memory for int array of n elements.

if (d.nums == 0) {
    /* Memory could not be allocated. */
} else {
    d.sym = "d";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        d.nums[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // d -> { "d", [ 1, 2, 3 ] }

    free(d.nums); // Free the allocated memory.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear, but I think you want to be able to access the individual characters.  Is this what you are looking for?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char* name[] = {"a1","b2","c3"};
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        printf("%s = %c %c\n",name[i],name[i][0],name[i][1]);
}
```

#### Output:

```
a1 = a 1
b2 = b 2
c3 = c 3
```