# How to get a string using pointer and print it again?

Tags: c

I tried with the following code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    char *a;
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
    }
```

I can enter a string but nothing is printed in the screen.

Comment: There are millions of examples of how to do this. Please, learn to do a little bit of research for yourself.

Comment: Well that looks like a seg-fault waiting to happen.

Comment: Look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983174/whats-wrong-with-this-scanf

Comment: possible duplicate of [making use of string pointer to print the character-integer combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484376/making-use-of-string-pointer-to-print-the-character-integer-combinations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By allocating some memory before using it.

```
char *a;
a=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
scanf("%s",a);
printf("%s",a);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *a = (char *) malloc(512 * sizeof(char));
```

c is rigorous you should do all the preliminary work

Comment: Elaborate more on what this does and why it's necessary. As it stands, it's unclear to the OP why this could help.